# Can't bring in Vue from import but can access it if I bring it in html file

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, import, module

So I'm switching from React over to Vue and have just a simple hello world sort of project up that works only when I bring in Vue in `script` tag in my HTML file. However I can't import the node module like:

```
import './node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js
```

or

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

Like I said if I have a script in my HTML file such as

```
<script src='./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js'></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Then I can have in my `app.js`:

```
 new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello vue'
    }
});
```

And have it work just fine.

Why can I only bring Vue in from a script tag?

**Notes that might or might not matter**:
I used NPM and installed Vue through NPM it is listed in my dependencies.
I'm not using webpack or any sort of transpiler like babel.

Comment: check console for any errors. import is not supported by browsers you need to translate ES6 to ES5

Comment: @Dineshundefined thanks for the quick response. From what I understand is that browsers don't support require() either and I have tried using this import doesn't throw any errors other than vue not being defined but with chrome developer tools it still shows that the resource is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="app.js" type="module"></script>
```

You have to declare the script as of type "module" to tell the browser it's an ES6 module file and then you can use the `import` keyword assuming your browser supports it. Browser support: https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I have done this and it still presents the same issue as before.